# new fragment squeezing old fragment on add method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I um uzing this code:

```
    FragmentManager FManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction FTransaction =  FManager.beginTransaction();
    FTransaction.setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragment.setArguments(fragment.getArguments());
    FTransaction.add(ResourceId, fragment, label);
    FTransaction.addToBackStack(backStack);
    FTransaction.commit();
```

and I m geting this on my activity:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9NKy.png

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that my simple answer will help you. Currently, You are loading an another fragment over your main fragment. you need to "hide" or "remove" or "replace" with old one. As i mentioned them below

In case of Remove or Hide

```
Fragment fr2 = fragmentManger.findFragmentByTag(Constants.TAG_Detail_Page);
if (fr2 != null)
    fragmentTransaction.remove(fr2);
```

While for "Replace", you will assign new fragment to contentView:

```
FTransaction .replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
```

Comment: have difference if I am using a unique XML Resource and changing the fragment inside him ?

Comment: here in my answer, fragment_container is my respective unique XML Resource.

Comment: I Found the problem. I was using a XML Resource with a tag Fragment. I just replace the Fragment tag to Layout Tag and done. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the fragment manager to add another fragment and it is doing just that.  You never tell it to do anything to the original fragment.  If you want to remove the exisitng fragment and show a new one then you should be calling:

```
FTransaction.replace(...)
```

instead of calling add.

If the original fragment has been added via the xml layout file, it is more difficult to replace. There are multiple SO questions dealing with that situation.